# Fireworks fullscreen mode not working

Tags: adobe-fireworks

[image: Screenshot of the Fireworks Menu]

So I'm working on an Adobe Fireworks project, but I am no longer able to enter fullscreen mode. I linked an image of the buttons that don't react. The keyboard shortcut (F) doesn't work either. When I click them nothing happens.

I tried restarting the program and also searched for solutions on the internet without success.

This is on Windows 10. Does anybody have an idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: A (best case) 2012 application on a 2015 operating system will almost always have "quirks" you simply have to learn to live with if you aren't willing to upgrade the software, or downgrade the operating system.

Comment: Sure, but it has been working yesterday, so I was wondering if maybe anybody else had already had this problem and possibly found a solution.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably time to ditch Fireworks

Comment: @Maharkus - if it was working yesterday, then perhaps a Windows update broke it. Or perhaps it's just a glitch. Have you tried restarting the computer, and the application? Have you tried running the software in compatibility mode?

Comment: @BillyKerr Running the software in compatibility mode actually did the trick! Thank you! Probably a problem with a windows update. You can write it as the answer if you want, I'll choose it as correct answer

Comment: @Maharkus OK, I did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you say, the software was working yesterday, then perhaps a recent Windows update broke it.

Here are some things to try before "ditching it".

1. Have you tried restarting the computer, and the application? It could just be a glitch.
2. Have you tried running the software in compatibility mode in Windows?  This sometimes works quite well for older software.